Taiwan village level household data?
I'm searching for Taiwan household/income data, but at a village, or at least township level, has anyone ever found it? I can't seem to find it anywhere! Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!!

Are you looking for disposable income, savings, household equipment count on household level?
